# Delete a stucture containing a vector -- munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c++

On my linux (Ubuntu) machine, the following piece of code gives a munmap_chunk():invalid pointer error.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int id;
    vector<int> successors;
};

int main() {

    node* G = new node [2];
    delete G;
}
```

Thank you for your suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `delete[]` on dynamically allocated arrays:

```
delete G; //wrong 
delete[] G; //right
```