# How delete safely struct allocated with new?

Tags: c++, valgrind, destructor

I'm trying to create a little bit complicated data structure, this is a simple demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Item;
struct Store;

struct globalEnviroment
{
     Item * data;
     globalEnviroment(Item * paramData) : data(paramData){}            
     ~globalEnviroment()
     {
        delete data;
     }
};

struct Item
{
        int id;
        std::vector<std::string>* names;

        Item() {};
        ~Item ( ) {delete names;}
};

int main ( )
{
    Item * items = new Item[3];
    items[0].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[1].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[2].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    globalEnviroment * ge = new globalEnviroment(items);

    delete ge;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

error on `delete data;` line.

I am not sure what is the right way to delete object of the type globalEnviroment. Is my destructor works right?

Comment: Put the whole memory management inside of the struct. Or better yet don't use `new` / `delete` at all, you don't need to do so for most cases in c++, it's different from java.

Comment: Memory allocated with `new[]` has to be deleted with `delete[]`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `new Item[3]` if you already use `std::vector` at another place? And why do you want to use `std::vector<std::string> * names` instead of just `std::vector<std::string> names`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a stucture containing a vector -- munmap\_chunk(): invalid pointer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846555/delete-a-stucture-containing-a-vector-munmap-chunk-invalid-pointer)

Comment: And if you have a `delete` in the destructor then your class should either not be copy or assignable or need to ensure that the raw pointer is not copied, otherwise, your code is prone to double frees.

Comment: why do you make it complicated? Just dont use `new` and everything will be simpler. There is no apparent reason to use a single `new` or `delete` in your code

Comment: if you want to make an exercise using pointers correct your current error then go further, you can look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in the destructor of *globalEnviroment*

- the definition of *Item* is unknown, you do not have warning when you compile ?
- `delete data;` must be `delete [] data;` (in the current case where you created the instance giving i argument the result of a `new Items[...]` rather than the result of `new Item`)

A first possibility is to move the definition of *Item* before the definition of *globalEnviroment*, also correcting the delete :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Item
{
        int id;
        std::vector<std::string>* names;

        Item() {};
        ~Item ( ) {delete names;}
};

struct globalEnviroment
{
     Item * data;
     globalEnviroment(Item * paramData) : data(paramData){}            
     ~globalEnviroment()
     {
        delete [] data;
     }
};

int main ( )
{
    Item * items = new Item[3];
    items[0].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[1].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[2].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    globalEnviroment * ge = new globalEnviroment(items);

    delete ge;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==13369== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13369== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13369== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13369== Command: ./a.out
==13369== 
==13369== 
==13369== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13369==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13369==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 20,296 bytes allocated
==13369== 
==13369== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13369== 
==13369== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13369== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

A second possibility is to move the definition of the destructor after the definition of *Item* :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Item;

struct globalEnviroment
{
     Item * data;
     globalEnviroment(Item * paramData) : data(paramData){}            
     ~globalEnviroment();
};

struct Item
{
        int id;
        std::vector<std::string>* names;

        Item() {};
        ~Item ( ) {delete names;}
};

globalEnviroment::~globalEnviroment()
{
  delete [] data;
}

int main ( )
{
    Item * items = new Item[3];
    items[0].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[1].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    items[2].names = new std::vector<std::string>();
    globalEnviroment * ge = new globalEnviroment(items);

    delete ge;

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation and executions give the same result

---

Out of that

- having pointer(s) in your class(es) you have to take care of the assignment, copy constructor etc, you have to define them.
- the constructor of *Item* does not initialize *names* to NULL, if you do not set the field after the destructor will have undefined behavior
- you have to suppose *data* if initialized with an array of *Items* or just an *Item*, but you code will compile perfectly whatever you call its constructor with `newItem` or `new Item[..]` in argument.

If you want to make an exercise using pointers, do not stop at the beginning, got further ;-)